Python Modulo operator bug
I'm using Python version 3.9.12. I asked Python what the remainder of -7 divided by 3 is (-7%3), and it answered 2! It should be -1, right? Am I getting it wrong? What's going on?

no, this is the mathematically sane way to define the modulus operator. of course, there are other ways it is defined to treat negative numbers, but this is the best way. Other programming languages use other definitions, e.g. C and Java

@chepner Not true, for example 7 % -3 is -2, which isn't between 0 and abs(-3).
